# how to render line breaks to single newlines in docsifiy

Tags: html, markdown, docsify

I like to write markdown files in VScode and preview the rendered HTML via the MPE (Markdown-preview-enhanced) plugin, where line breaks are simply rendered as newlines in the default settings, and Github Flavored Markdown does the same thing, although I know the standard should be to use more than two spaces plus a line break.

Can I achieve this by modifying `index.html`

default setting of mpe
[mpe_break_on_single_newline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFIUI.png)
how to modify the `index.html` to achieve the following
[indexhtml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mA5Va.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit the `index.html` like this

```
...
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script>
    window.$docsify = {
      markdown: {
        breaks: true,
        // Other markdown options
      }
    }
  </script>
  <!-- Docsify v4 -->
  <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/docsify@4"></script>
</body>
...
```